# create a mysql query with using php arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have and arrray below

```
  $titles=array("Dr.","Ms.","Mr.");
```

after foreach loop, i create the query below

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE title = 'Dr.' or title = 'Ms.' or title = 'Mr.' ) group by sentences
```

OUTPUT start from

Mr.
Ms.
Mr.
Dr.

I want to PUT the DR. first that Ms. than Mr. which is in order inside of the array()

Answer (score 4):

As long as your input is sanitized, you can use `implode` to prepare the statement.

```
$stmt = 'SELECT * FROM `table` ';
$stmt .= "WHERE title = '" . implode("' OR title = '", $titles) . "'";
```

**Result**

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE title = 'Dr.' OR title = 'Ms.' OR title = 'Mr.'
```

[See a demo](http://codepad.org/uen6hbsk)

You can alternatively use `IN`:

```
$stmt = 'SELECT * FROM `table` ';
$stmt .= "WHERE title IN ('" . implode("', '", $titles) . "')";
```

**Result**

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE title IN ('Dr.', 'Ms.', 'Mr.')
```

You need to fix your `GROUP BY`; you're not using it correctly.

If you want to sort the order of your titles, you can try:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN title = 'Dr' THEN 1
    WHEN title = 'Ms.' THEN 2
    WHEN title = 'Mr.' THEN 3
    ELSE 4
  END
```

Comment: still not in order

SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE title
IN (
'Dr.', 'Ms.', 'Mr.'
)
LIMIT 0 , 30

Answer (score 0):

you can try *in* statement which is easy to read.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `urls` 
WHERE  `id` 
IN ( 1, 2, 4 ) 
ORDER BY  `urls`.`id` ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```